# Difference between having array inside form and posting it

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array, laravel-4

**Here is my array**

```
$datas = array(array('studentid' => '9','toschool' => '4','tohome'=>'4'),array('studentid' => '10','toschool' => '4','tohome'=>'4'));
```

When i return this i am getting as

```
return $data;
```

Output :

```
[{"studentid":"9","toschool":"4","tohome":"4"},{"studentid":"10","toschool":"4","tohome":"4"}]
```

I want to get this same array from the postman

So, i pasted the ouput for the name as data

And i receive it as

```
$gotdata = Input::get('data');
```

and when i print i got the same output

```
[{"studentid":"9","toschool":"4","tohome":"4"},{"studentid":"10","toschool":"4","tohome":"4"}]
```

When i tried to save the record, the $data works

```
MYModel::insert($data);
```

But the

```
MTIServiceAttendance::insert($gotdata);
```

And it throws the error as

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::insert() must be of the type array, string given
```

How can i fix this so that the $gotdata should be saved.

Note : for the Model the input should be

```
MTIServiceAttendance::insert(array(array('studentid' => '9','toschool' => '4','tohome'=>'4'),array('studentid' => '10','toschool' => '4','tohome'=>'4')));
```

What should i do to make the input form like this array ?

### Update : Here is the var_dump of the arrays

Return :

```
return var_dump($data);
```

Output :

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(3) { ["studentid"]=> string(1) "9" ["toschool"]=> string(1) "4" ["tohome"]=> string(1) "4" } [1]=> array(3) { ["studentid"]=> string(2) "10" ["toschool"]=> string(1) "4" ["tohome"]=> string(1) "4" } }
```

Return :

```
return var_dump($gotdata);
```

Output :

```
string(94) "[{"studentid":"9","toschool":"4","tohome":"4"},{"studentid":"10","toschool":"4","tohome":"4"}]"
```

Comment: Can you make a `var_dump` of `$gotdata`?

Comment: I have updated my question with the `var_dump` of the `$data` and `$gotdata`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$gotdata` is a JSON string representation of your array. So while it looks the same in your first output you can clearly see the difference when using `var_dump`. Simply use `json_decode` to convert it in an array:

```
$gotdata = Input::get('data');
$gotdata = json_decode($gotdata, true);
MTIServiceAttendance::insert($gotdata);
```

Comment: Ah, i am getting `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string` error

Comment: Hmm. what do you get when var_dumping the result of `json_decode`?

Comment: The `var_dump` of `json_decode` is `array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#524 (3) { ["studentid"]=> string(1) "9" ["toschool"]=> string(1) "4" ["tohome"]=> string(1) "4" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#515 (3) { ["studentid"]=> string(2) "10" ["toschool"]=> string(1) "4" ["tohome"]=> string(1) "4" } }`

Comment: Use `true` as second parameter to `json_decode`. That will convert it into an associative array instead of objects. How `insert()` likes it ;)

Comment: Yeah man,, I have updated to `$gotdata = json_decode($gotdata, true);` and that makes the sense :)

Comment: Good. Note that if your request only holds json data and sends the correct content type header Laravel *should* automatically convert the data from JSON to an array. Then you could just do `Input::all()`...

Comment: Yeah yes, `Input:all();`  will do but i have some other parameter like id to identify it, so i will use `Input::except(array('id'))` :)

Comment: you can use `Input::json('data')` and get rid of second line `$gotdata = json_decode($gotdata, true);`

Comment: @K.Toress Oh yes, forgot about that. Thanks

Comment: @K.Tores No, when i try `Input::json('data');` i am getting same error `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::insert() must be of the type array, null given` so i use `json_decode($gotdata, true);`

Comment: I think that's because `Input::json()` assumes the full request is json not just one input value...

Comment: Yes because when i returning the `Input::json('data')` it returns `NULL`